# Why I can't launch robot in RViz after following a tutorial? Cant find launch file

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new here. I'm trying to control a robot through Moveit. I've been following the tutorials of Moveit. First I do the tutorial and then I try to follow with my robot. So far only opening it and moving it manually.

I opened the URDF, from the robot I'm using ( it is opensource:  https://github.com/b-adkins/thor_arm_moveit ), I just followed the instructions

The last tutorial I followed was : Move Group Python Interface ( http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html ). Basically just seeing an animation of the tutorial robot.

But now I can't even open my robot. When I write in the terminal " roslaunch thor_arm_moveit demo.launch  " the error it shows is:

```
RLException: while processing /home/john/DAHcatkin_ws/src/thor_arm_moveit/launch/move_group.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/john/DAHcatkin_ws/src/thor_arm_moveit/launch/move_group.launch'
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I investigated and maybe found  that the problem is it believes the launch is in a place that isn't. The file does exist, since I was able to open it before the tutorial but cant find it now. Other answer I found was that the python file of the tutorial is linked to home and that affects it as well? idk. How do I fix this?

This may be crucial, or not, but I have a workspace for each robot. DAHcatkin_ws is the thor robot I have irl and ws_moveit for the tutorial robot. I'm still trying to understand workstations.

My background is mechanics, so all this is new for me, maybe the error is obvious. Please try to tell me the steps to solve it and not just the general idea.

don't know if this is useful, but my info is:
ROS melodic
kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345997/why-i-can%27t-launch-robot-in-rviz-after-following-a-tutorial?-cant-find-launch-file/) by [Rosfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/52281/rosfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A coworker who knows ROS well, helped me solve this. Apparently there was a file in a folder in src he cut it and paste it with all the other files, and rename the folder to a different name.
it
And that solve it.

---

Originally posted by [Rosfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/52281/rosfan/) with karma: 16 on 2020-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0